# How to approach removing needless instantiation when calling native method from WebAPI

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a dotnet core WebAPI web server that needs to execute a native method written in Win32 C++. The problem is, each time this method is called it needs to instantiate a bunch of things before it can do what it needs to do, this adds delays to the request. (It's currently using DLLImport to access the C++ method in the compiled DLL).

What I would like to do is have some sort of long running process start when the server starts, which will handle the initialization once, then have my WebAPI service call a method inside this process that executes the code that I actually need to run immediately, without the need to initialize its dependencies each time. Since this is a web server, the process will need to be able to handle multiple requests at once.

What is the recommended approach for this? I have full access to the C++ code and the WebAPI server code so I'm free to do whatever needs to be done to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set-up some IPC infrastructure between the two. 
One way to do it would be to make your DLL COM compatible. I.e having the DLL be a COM server to some COM class. The server process would then 'CreateInstance' a class, which will automatically launch your native process. A call would then just be a normal function call, COM will handle the RPC.

Another simpler way will be using a named memory-mapped file. Both processes will open a handle to this, there you can store a queue or some data structure. The server process will push while the native process will pop. You can use windows events to synchronize this. You can write this yourself or use something like boost::interprocess for the C++ part. I assume there may be other IPC libraries you may find for this.

You can also use a Pipe, I know C# has some easy ways to handle windows pipes. Pipes do not need synchronization but to efficiently handle a number of such requests you may need a number of threads on the native process to read from the pipe.

Personally i'd go with using COM if that is possible. As it will hide for you the low-level IPC stuff that may be a pit-fall. It is a bit longer to set-up though.

Comment: Awesome, I've taken a look at the pipes option and I've decided to go ahead and implement that one. Seems the simplest from I can see. Thanks for the explanation.